# Know which bytes are opcode and which operands in IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, disassemblers

I want to extract a generic signature of a function in IDA and wanted to use just the opcodes of the instructions without its operands.

Example:

[image]

From the first instruction I want to know the bytes that tell the disassembler that it is a MOVZX instruction.

From the second and third one the ones that say it is a MOV instruction (probably 8B).

And so on..

I'm aware that some instructions have modifiers. I just want to know the bytes that translate to certain **mnemonic.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is not solvable since the opcode and operands may be sharing the same bytes (e. g. some instructions encode part of their opcode in the mod R/M byte, which can also  contain some of the operands at the same time), but you can get some  approximation by inspecting the `Operands` array of the `insn_t` structure returned by the `decode_insn` function. The `offb` member of each `op_t` element is supposed to be the offset of the bytes corresponding to the operand in the instruction bytes.

Note that it may be 0 since it’s not always possible to determine operand location at the byte level, especially on non-x86 architectures. For more info check the [`ua.hpp` header](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/ua_8hpp.html) in the SDK.

Comment: Or you could use insn_t::itype

Comment: Note also that many risc cpu's store operands as bitfields in the opcode.